# What does the phrase "these developments" reference?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "these developments" refer back to "The moderation we see among nonfundamentalists"? In the previous sentence before the following quoted, there is the phrase "democratic politics, scientific advancement in every frontt, concern for human rights, an end to cultural and geographic isolation, ect.); so it probably refers back to the phrase. I am not sure.

> The doors leading out of scriptural literalism do not open from the inside. The moderation we see among nonfundamentalists is not some sign that faith itself has evolved; it is, rather the product of the many hammer blows of modernity that have exposed certain tenets of faith to doubt. **Not the least among these developments** has been the emergence of our tendency to value evidence and to be convinced by a proposition to the degree that there is evidence for it.

> Source: The End of Faith by Sam Harris (PDF)

Comment: Idiomatically, we usually ***don't*** include the definite article in introductory ***Not least among these...***  - [particularly over the past century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Not+least+among+these%2CNot+the+least+among+these&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNot%20least%20among%20these%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNot%20the%20least%20among%20these%3B%2Cc0), it's just ***Not least among these...***

Comment: (***these developments*** loosely refers back to preceding ***the many hammer blows of modernity***.)

Comment: You mean you have no problem understanding *scriptural literalism* but not *these developments*? Come on now. Do yourself a favor and find an easier text to read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it *only* refers to that. I understand the "developments" to refer to the 'evolution' of faith.

> The moderation we see among nonfundamentalists is not some sign that **faith itself has evolved**.

The "moderation we see among nonfundamentalists" is cited as being just one part of that evolution.